# Probability that second card is red in standard deck.

Tags: probability

I understand that you can do (26/52)(51/51) since order doesn't matter in the multiplication rule.. but how would you do it if you had to express it in chronological order?Can you also express it using some version of the binomial coefficient?

Comment: You need to split into two cases. The probability that the second card is red depends on whether the first card was red or black.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways the second card can be red: either the first is black and the second is red, with probability $\frac{26}{52}\cdot\frac{26}{51}$, or the first two cards are red, with probability $\frac{26}{52}\cdot\frac{25}{51}$. Adding these gives the desired probability.

Using binomial coefficients, there are $\binom{52}{26}$ total ways to choose which cards in the deck are red. If the second card is red, there are $\binom{51}{25}$ ways to choose which cards are red among the remaining 51 card. Thus, the probability of a card being red is
$$
\frac{\binom{51}{25}}{\binom{52}{26}}
$$